# Editing labels of series in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have data listed in columns as below and by highlighting it all including the names and the units and then clicking `Insert -> Diagram...`, I can easily make the following graph:

[image]

The labels are correct `LabelA`, `Labelb`, and `LabelC` in this case.

But if the label names are *not* in the same column as the data, then I cannot make this graph. In the data structure below where names and data are in different columns, I again highlight all data cells as well as their units and names (by holding down the `ctrl` button and clicking all the cells with the cursor):

[image]

It is clear that the software does not know that it should assign the names as labels. Is there a method to make the graph show the correct labeling as in the first scenario but with the second scenario's data structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could combine the data in another place with formula:

```
={{A1,C1,E1};{B4:B6,D4:D6,F4:F6}}
```

and then plot the diagram as usual.